# Access meteor user email

Tags: meteor-accounts

typical schema:

```
 emails: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"emails.$": {
    type: Object
},
"emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
},
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
},
```

I have a form that edits the meteor.user emails field . I want to access this field after the form is submitted to a method but having difficulty doing so.

```
  somemethod: function(doc){
   //i have tried but i get undefined
    console.log(doc.emails[0].address) 

  }
```

how do i get this? Thank you.